# rename folders with case-sensitive names

Tags: linux, bash, command, rename, case-sensitive

I want to rename folder with case-sensitive option. for example:

```
mv "foldername1" "foldername2"
```

an error occuring in this command, because name of my folder isn't "foldername1", it is "FolderName1".

How can I use rename (mv) command to rename case-sensitive named folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls | grep -i foldername1 | xargs -I {} mv {} foldername2
```

Warning: You would not like to use this when multiple candidate files (eg. if foldername1 and Foldername1 are both present).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` command:

```
find . -iname foldername1 -exec mv '{}' foldername2 ;
```